# owl carousel animated items hover keeps original position

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations, owl-carousel-2

I'm Using owl on [**my website**](http://www.comeonswiss.com/) and you can see after going to the end of the items and then coming back, hovering on items have issues, some text remain and make the hover transition buggy
this is not the first time this happens,usually when i apply animations to owl items, looks like owl creates a duplicate of the item and then animates that item, so the original item remains at its position.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce that bug. The items move on hovering (Win7 / Chrome).

Comment: I use chrome on windows 10 and 7, both produce the bug.

Comment: I can reproduce it, when I go to the right with the arrows and then back to the left. I didn't understand your "to the end of the items" (thought you meant the bottom of the page).

Answer (score 0):

Animate .owl-item instead of the slide inside, this solved my issue with opacity animations looking buggy.

Comment: currently hover and animations are being used by owl-item... not the whole slide